# Why am I getting org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array?

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

I have this function:

```
fun getFeed(token: String): Result<Array<Post?>, Exception> {
        if (token != "") {
            val (request, response, result) = "https://alles.cx/api/feed"
                .httpGet()
                .header("Authorization", token.toString())
                .response()

            when (result) {
                is Result.Success -> {
                    println("Result success")
                    try {
                        val responseJSON = JSONObject(String(response.data))
                        if (!responseJSON.has("err")) {
                            println("Has no error")
                            var feedArray = arrayOfNulls<Post>(0)
                            println("HERE?")
                            var feed = JSONArray(responseJSON["feed"])   // <-----ERROR HERE 
                            println("not here")
                            println("Made to the for")
                            for (i in 0 until feed.length()) {
                                println("For $i")
                                val jsonObject = feed.getJSONObject(i)

                                var imageURL: URL? = null
                                if (jsonObject.has("image")) {
                                    imageURL = URL(jsonObject["image"].toString())
                                }
                                feedArray[i] = Post(
                                    jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                    User(jsonObject.getJSONObject("author").getString("id"), jsonObject.getJSONObject("author").getString("username"), jsonObject.getJSONObject("author").getString("name")),
                                    jsonObject.getString("createdAt"),
                                    jsonObject.getInt("replyCount"),
                                    jsonObject.getInt("score"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("content"),
                                    null,
                                    imageURL,
                                    jsonObject.getInt("vote")

                                )
                                println("Added post $i")
                            }
                            println(feedArray)
                            return Result.Success(feedArray)
                        }
                        else {
                            println("yes error")
                            return Result.Failure(Exception(responseJSON["err"].toString()))
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e: Exception) {
                        return Result.Failure(e)
                    }
                }
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    return Result.Failure(Exception(result.component2()?.localizedMessage))
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return Result.Failure(Exception("badAuth"))
        }
    }
```

An error is occurring on this line. I know this because of the print statements that are in the code:

```
var feed = JSONArray(responseJSON["feed"])   // <-----ERROR HERE
```

This is what the error that is occurring is.

```
[Failure: org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray]
```

This is what the feed object from the get request will look like, just so you have an idea of what it is:

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "equ2ZfaX2UThtkS8DzkXdc",
            "author": {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "name": "Archie",
                "username": "archie",
                "plus": true
            },
            "content": "I know it's quite inactive here atm. But I'm doing tons of stuff behind the scenes - basically rewriting the entire platform from scratch. Micro will be done by the end of the summer.",
            "image": null,
            "createdAt": "2020-07-30T20:39:23.000Z",
            "score": 5,
            "vote": 0,
            "replyCount": 0,
            "hasParent": false
        }
    ]
}
```

What could possibly be going wrong here. I am using Fuel for the request, but I don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the correct way to get the array would be to do `var feed = responseJSON.getJSONArray("feed")`.  You're implementation calls the `JSONArray(Object o)` constructor which is meant to be called only for primitive arrays (`int[]`, `double[]`, etc.) as they cannot be effectively typed using generics). Thus the constructor complains as you pass in an object which is not a primitive array.